# Save Session Objects in Cookies with Struts2

Tags: java, session, cookies, struts2

Is there an easy way to store my session objects in cookies instead in memory with Struts2?

Thanks

Comment: Not really. There is a limit to cookie data and so you aren't going to be able to store much in a cookie. If you're talking about storing simple data like a string, number, boolean, or some other simple type, then cookies would work, but if you are going to serialize a complex object into a cookie, you may run into problems. Additionally, you need to be careful to protect yourself from the client transmitting an object in a state you aren't expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try set the value you need to cookies, then you can read it with an Interceptor or Action, depending on what you need. Here is how I set the cookies in Struts2.

The setCookie method, as parameters pass response, cookie name, cookie value, and period

response:

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) 
ActionContext.getContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_RESPONSE);
```

and period, something like this: 
60 * 60 * 24 * 365 (for a year)

```
public static void setCookie(HttpServletResponse response, String name, String value, int period) {

    try {

        Cookie div = new Cookie(name, value);
        div.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365); // Make the cookie last a year
        response.addCookie(div);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(StrutsUtils.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "message", e);
    }
}
```

The getCookie method, as parameters pass the request object and cookie name

request:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);


public static String getCookie(HttpServletRequest request, String name) {

    String value = null;

    try {

        for (Cookie c : request.getCookies()) {
            if (c.getName().equals(name)) {
                value = c.getValue();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(StrutsUtils.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "message", e);
    }

    return value;
}
```